# Multiple Timeframes in same screen

Tags: pine-script

I am trading BTC/USD and I trying to export the following in the same screen:

- 2 different time frames, eg 1D and 3D charts.
- both of them with candle charts.
- overlay false of course.
- add the second chart as an indicator maybe.

The security (syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close), etc., will give me only the close, or high, or low or average so I will not be able to see the actual candle charts.

Basically Imagine that you open two different webpages for a commodity with different time charts and you want to combine them in one screen (of course just minimizing the browsers and align them it is not what I am talking about, I am saying through pine script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help get you started:

```
//@version=4
study("")
res = input("D", type = input.resolution)
[o, h, l, c] = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, [open, high, low, close])
plotcandle(o, h, l, c, "res candles", c > o ? color.teal : color.red)
```

[image]